# Java Binary Tree Main Method

Tags: java, tree

I've got a class Node

```
class Node{
    int val; 
    Node parent; 
    Node left; 
    Node right; 

    public Node (int val){
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

And I have a few methods:

```
 public class Tree{
 public Node root = null;

 void insertNodeSorted(Node x, Node tree) {
    if (x.val < tree.val) {
        if (tree.left == null) {
            tree.left = x;
        }
        else
            insertNodeSorted(x, tree.left);
    }
    else {
        if (tree.right == null) {
            tree.right = x;
        }
        else
            insertNodeSorted(x, tree.right);
    }
} // end insertNodeSorted


void deleteNodeSorted(Node x) {
    if (root == null)
        return;
    else
        root = deleteNodeSorted(x, root);
}
Node deleteNodeSorted(Node x, Node tree) {
    if (x.val < tree.val)
        tree.left = deleteNodeSorted(x, tree.left);
    else if (x.val > tree.val)
        tree.right = deleteNodeSorted(x, tree.right);
    else
        tree = replaceNodeSorted(tree);
    return tree;
} // end deleteNodeSorted

// Additional Method
Node replaceNodeSorted(Node tree) {
    if (tree.right == null)
        tree = tree.left;
    else if (tree.left == null)
        tree = tree.right;
    else
        tree.right = findReplacement(tree.right, tree);
    return tree;
} // end replaceNodeSorted
Node findReplacement(Node tree, Node replace) {
    if (tree.left != null)
        tree.left = findReplacement(tree.left, replace);
    else {
        replace.val = tree.val;
        tree = tree.right;
    }
    return tree;
} // end findReplacement
```

And I'd like to compile the Tree, but I don't know what I exactly I need to write in the main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

  Tree t = new Tree();
  t.insertNodeSorted();
```

What do I have to write in the brackets in order to print the Tree? (I know I still have to add System.out.println(val); in the methods..)

Comment: This seems a little broad/vague. Populating a tree and printing it is a topic covered repeatedly and extensively in java. Do some research. As a side note, `t.insertNodeSorted()` won't compile. Where does a parameterless `insertNodeSorted` method exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined a variable holding the `root` node, so it is not necessary to pass the parameter `tree` for the method `insertNodeSorted`. You can use always the `root` node.

Add a method taking only one parameter.

```
public void insertNodeSorted(Node x) {
    if (root == null) {    
        root = x;
        return;
    }
    insertNodeSorted(x, root);
}
```

Define the other method with two parameters as `private`

```
 private void insertNodeSorted(Node x, Node tree) {
     ...
 }
```

Now you can insert elements as follow:

```
Tree t = new Tree();
t.insertNodeSorted(new Node(1));
t.insertNodeSorted(new Node(134));
t.insertNodeSorted(new Node(13));
t.insertNodeSorted(new Node(4));
...
```

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly to write System.out.println(x); to print the given values?

Comment: What do you exactly need to print?

Comment: All inserted Nodes

Comment: If you print them while inserting simply add System.out.println(x) as the first line of the method with one parameter. If you like to print the whole tree at any point you need to create a function to traverse the tree.

Comment: I don't know why, but it prints the reference Node@7852e922 and not the value I gave as a parameter if I write                                                           public void insertNodeSorted(Node x) {
        System.out.println(x);
        if (root == null) {
            root = x;
            return;
        }
        insertNodeSorted(x, root);
    }

Comment: You need to redefine the method toString() in the class Node.

Comment: public Strint toString() { return "Node value is " + value;} is a very small example